# filter bins in systemverilog transition functional coverage

Tags: system-verilog

Is there a way of limiting the bins generated in transition coverage in System Verilog cover points?

For example, I'd like to cover a transition *to* some value, and transition *away from* some value, but I don't care what the transition is to/from, and I don't want to write out a separate bin for each 'some value' in question.

```
module a  ;
   logic [7-1 : 0] b;

   covergroup c ;
      cp_aaa : coverpoint b {
         bins tr [] = ([0:128] => [0:128]) ;
      }
   endgroup
endmodule
```

produces 2^14 bins which is too many.

It would be nice to be able to have something like the following pseudocode:

```
bins tr [] = (notq => q)
   for q inside {[128-1:0]}
   where notq != q && notq inside {[128-1:0]};
```

and have it generate just 128 bins.

Yes, in this specific case, this is almost the same as saying `bins tr [] = {[128-1:0]}`, but I'm interested in the principle.

Ideally there would be a way to procedurally (not declaratively) generate bins...

Answer (score -1):

I would not attempt using transition bins for this- it's too complex. Use a `cross`

```
covergroup c;
currvalue: coverpoint q {
   bins v[128] = {[0:127]};
}
prevvalue: coverpoint prevq {
   bins v[128] = {[0:127]};
}
X: coverpoint q != prevq {
   bins xx = {1};   // 1 bin
}
to: cross currvalue,X; // creates 128 cross bins
away: cross prevvalue,X; 

endgroup
```

I didn't try this since you didn't give a complete example, but should get you close.

Comment: Like I said, I didn't try it. I was missing a `[`. You need to provide a complete example to test it.